# Randomizer Not working properly

Tags: c, random

I made a little randomizer and it's not working correctly. Here's the code...

I have a function,

```
short rnd(short *num){
    return (rand() % max) + 1;
}
```

which has a prototype of

```
short rnd(short *num);
```

When I use this, I do something like this:

```
max = 10;
num = rnd(&max);
```

the compiler throws no problems, but it is always equal to 0...
Any suggestions?

Comment: `max` must be a global variable for the code to compile.  Did you mean `*num` instead of `max`?  Also, if you don't assign to `*num`, why do you pass it as a pointer?

Comment: it is, im sorry. it's in a header file that is included...

Comment: Agree with Jonathan and also why using a pointer?

Comment: Ugh!  Global variables...in that function?  Ugh! Ugh! Ugh!  Don't do that.  Why on earth are you passing `num` if you're going to ignore it?

Comment: Ok that fixed it thanks! taking out the function arguments did it, it now makes a random number! Thank you @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your max is a global variable. I would recommend passing it to your rnd function as a parameter rather than making it global, and if it doesn't change at runtime just create a macro for your max and pass that in.

```
short rnd(unsigned short max)
{
  return (rand() % max) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a true random number it needs to be seeded. The best way to seed it is to use the time of the computer with srand() that is in the standard library.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
srand(time(NULL)); /*this in the main function*/

short rndnum(short max)
{
    return (short) (rand() % max) + 1;
}
```

this should produce random numbers between 1 and 10.